# Usage of @Componenscan in Springboot Spring MVC Application

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, intellij-idea, spring-boot

my problem is that i dont know how to specify the path for my Controller package to search for requestmapping annotations inside it in the @componenscan annotation, which is in the main class.

Project structure:
[image]

My DemoApplication class:

```
package com.personalitymeet;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan()
@Controller
public class DemoApplication {

@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping("/")
String entry(){
    return "bla";
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
}
}
```

Usercontroller.java:

```
package com.personalitymeet.web;

import com.personalitymeet.domain.User;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

/**
 * Created by mv on 15.09.2016.
 */

@Controller
public class UserController {

    @RequestMapping("/user")
    public String user(Model model){
        User user = new User();
        user.setFirstname("Misi");
        user.setLastname("Varga");
        model.addAttribute("user",user);
        return "userview";
    }

}
```

So, my question is, how can i tell springboots that it should search for @Requestmapping annotation in the Usercontroller class?

Comment: @EnableWebMvc do the trick

Comment: Add your gradle file.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify component scan to your configuration file to scan folder `com.personalitymeet` and it will automatically pick all the classes which has relevant annotations.

Below are basic 3 annotations needed to init application.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.personalitymeet")
```

Comment: With Spirng Boot you shouldn't need `@EnableWebMvc`.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem isn't the `@ComponentScan`, which will search in `com.personalitymeet` and all subpackages. It's that for some reason you don't have the MVC infrastructure activating.

You should have `spring-boot-starter-web` as a dependency in your `build.gradle` file, and you should add `@EnableWebMvc` to your configuration class.

Comment: It is in my gradle file:
dependencies {
 compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa')
 compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
 runtime('com.h2database:h2')
 testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
}

Comment: Only adding the dependency should be enough... Spring Boot detects that and automatically adds `@EnableWebMvc` configuration classes. If that isn't the case you are missing dependencies.

Comment: If you are using Spring Boot, adding `@EnableWebMvc` is almost certainly a bad idea. It'll switch off all of Spring Boot's auto-configuration of Spring MVC.

Comment: @AndyWilkinson Based on the dependencies implied, it looked like the Web starter was being included, and something else was suppressing the MVC autoconfig anyway.

Comment: Sorry to bother you, would you know if it is possible componentscan in two different domain packages? Or maybe should I join both domain under the same com... domain to make it work? 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77459796/how-to-scan-multiple-paths-with-different-root-paths-using-the-componentscan-an
@chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Can you replace this code:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan()
@Controller
public class DemoApplication {
...
```

With this code:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@Controller
public class DemoApplication {
...
```

Configure your application to expose the management endpoints:

```
http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#production-ready
```

and then hit this endpoint to see the endpoint exposed by the application:

```
http://localhost:[port]/manage/mappings
```

Also,  I recommend to create a separate controller for the root to keep your startup class uncluttered with application logic.