# How to scan multiple paths with different root paths error creating bean repository with not managed Entity type?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have to domain name packages com.domain.app and net.domain.app, MyApplication where @SpringBootApplication is in **com.domain.app** but I now implementing new stuff in **net.domain.app**

I have @Service and it work well but with the addition of @Repository I had to add @EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"com.domain.app", "net.domain.app"}) to solve the error and next issue is with @Entity.

I am getting this error on a second domain package name that seems to not to find managed bean with @Entity.

Any idea why is happening and how to solve this?

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: 
Error creating bean with name 'userService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'repo'; 
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Error creating bean with name 'userRepository' defined in net.conselldemallorca.sirh.business.security.boundary.UserRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on MyApplication: 
Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class net.domain.app.security.entity.User
...
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Error creating bean with name 'userRepository' defined in net.domain.app.security.boundary.UserRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on MyApplication: 
Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
Not a managed type: class net.domain.app.security.entity.User
...
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
Not a managed type: class net.domain.app.security.entity.User
```

MyApplication.java

```
package com.domain.app;
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.domain.app", "net.domain.app"})
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"com.domain.app", "net.domain.app"})
public class MyApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

UserRepository.java

```
package net.domain.app.security.boundary;
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {
...
}
```

UserService.java

```
package net.domain.app.security.boundary;
@Service
@Transactional(rollbackFor = Throwable.class)
public class UserService implements UserServiceable {
   @Autowired
   UserRepository repo;
...
}
```

User.java

```
package net.domain.app.security.entity;

import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Objects;
...
@Entity
@Table(name = "USER")
public class User implements Serializable {
...
}
```

Comment: Hello Joe, could you provide the imports used in the User class ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be added @EntityScan with the domain packages you want to search into.

MyApplication.java

```
package com.domain.app;
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.domain.app", "net.domain.app"})
@EntityScan(basePackages = {"com.domain.app", "net.domain.app"})
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"com.domain.app", "net.domain.app"})
public class MyApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```